# Compare two JSON arrays using two or more columns values in Dataweave 2.0

Tags: filter, dataweave, mulesoft

I had a task where I needed to compare and filter two `JSON` arrays based on the same values using one column of each array. So I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62187694/6621346) answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62180696/compare-2-json-arrays-to-get-matching-and-un-matching-outputs) question.

However, now I need to compare two `JSON` arrays matching two, or even three columns values.

I already tried to use one `map` inside other, however, it isn't working.

The examples could be the ones in the answer I used. Compare `db.code = file.code`, `db.name = file.nm` and `db.id = file.identity`

```
var db = [
    {
        "CODE": "A11",
        "NAME": "Alpha",
        "ID": "C10000"
    },
    {
        "CODE": "B12",
        "NAME": "Bravo",
        "ID": "B20000"
    },
    {
        "CODE": "C11",
        "NAME": "Charlie",
        "ID": "C30000"
    },
    {
        "CODE": "D12",
        "NAME": "Delta",
        "ID": "D40000"
    },
    {
        "CODE": "E12",
        "NAME": "Echo",
        "ID": "E50000"
    }
]  



var file = [
    {
        "IDENTITY": "D40000",
        "NM": "Delta",
        "CODE": "D12"
    },
    {
        "IDENTITY": "C30000",
        "NM": "Charlie",
        "CODE": "C11"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this works for you

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var file = [
    {
        "IDENTITY": "D40000",
        "NM": "Delta",
        "CODE": "D12"
    },
    {
        "IDENTITY": "C30000",
        "NM": "Charlie",
        "CODE": "C11"
    }
]
var db = [
    {
        "CODE": "A11",
        "NAME": "Alpha",
        "ID": "C10000"
    },
    {
        "CODE": "B12",
        "NAME": "Bravo",
        "ID": "B20000"
    },
    {
        "CODE": "C11",
        "NAME": "Charlie",
        "ID": "C30000"
    },
    {
        "CODE": "D12",
        "NAME": "Delta",
        "ID": "D40000"
    },
    {
        "CODE": "E12",
        "NAME": "Echo",
        "ID": "E50000"
    }
]
---
file flatMap(v) -> ( 
    db filter (v.IDENTITY == $.ID and v.NM == $.NAME and v.CODE == $.CODE)
)
```

Using `flatMap` instead of `map` to flatten otherwise will get array of arrays in the output which is cleaner unless you are expecting a possibility of multiple matches per `file` entry, in which case I'd stick with `map`.

Answer (score 3):

You can compare objects in DW directly, so the solution you linked can be modified to the following:

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json
var db = [
    {
        "CODE": "A11",
        "NAME": "Alpha",
        "ID": "C10000"
    },
    {
        "CODE": "B12",
        "NAME": "Bravo",
        "ID": "B20000"
    },
    {
        "CODE": "C11",
        "NAME": "Charlie",
        "ID": "C30000"
    },
    {
        "CODE": "D12",
        "NAME": "Delta",
        "ID": "D40000"
    },
    {
        "CODE": "E12",
        "NAME": "Echo",
        "ID": "E50000"
    }
]  

var file = [
    {
        "IDENTITY": "D40000",
        "NM": "Delta",
        "CODE": "D12"
    },
    {
        "IDENTITY": "C30000",
        "NM": "Charlie",
        "CODE": "C11"
    }
]
---
db partition (e) -> file contains {IDENTITY:e.ID,NM:e.NAME,CODE:e.CODE}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `filter` directly and using `contains`

```
db filter(value) -> file contains {IDENTITY: value.ID, NM: value.NAME, CODE: value.CODE}
```

This tells you to filter the db array based on if the file contains the object `{IDENTITY: value.ID, NM: value.NAME, CODE: value.CODE}`. However, this will not work if objects in the file array has other fields that you will not use for comparison. Using above, you can update filter condition to check if an object in file array exist (using data selector) where the condition applies. You can use below to check that.

```
db filter(value) -> file[?($.IDENTITY==value.ID and $.NM == value.NAME and $.CODE == value.CODE)] != null
```